# How to compute KL-divergence when there are categories of zero counts?

Tags: distributions, information-theory, kullback-leibler, laplace-smoothing

I have two very large discrete frequency distributions (about 4 million items), and each contains many items with counts of 0. I want to calculate the KL divergence between them and use the empirical probability as the probability estimate. However, this seems to result in a negative value, which if I understand correctly, should not be possible with KL divergence, and I think it's because there are counts of 0.

For instance, if I run the following R code, I get a negative:

```
library(philentropy)

mat <- matrix(
  rep(1:271, each = 2), # 271 or higher all yield negative values
  nrow = 2
)
mat[2, 1] <- 0
KL(mat, est.prob = "empirical")

Result: -7.181671e-08
```

If I add a very small fixed number to every count, though, I get a very small but positive result:

```
mat <- mat + 0.01
KL(mat, est.prob = "empirical")

Result: 0.0001433061
```

Essentially, I'm using Laplace smoothing (I think) to get rid of 0 counts. Is this statistically valid, though?

Comment: Bayesian smoothing is one acceptable approach but only add noise to zero counts. see  also for an excellent answer https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72668/how-to-compute-kl-divergence-when-pmf-contains-0s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is valid to do smoothing if you have good reason to believe the probability of any specific to occur is not actually zero and you just didn't have a large enough sample size to view it.

Besides for it many times being a good idea to use an additive smoothing approach the KL divergence cannot be less than zero.

The reason it came out zero is probably an implementation issue and not because the true calculation using the estimated probabilities gave a negative result. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence for a discussion on the non-negativity of KL divergence.

The question is also why you want to calculate the KL divergence. Do you want to compare multiple distributions and see which is closes to some specific distribution? In this case, probably it's better for the package you are using to do smoothing and this shouldn't rank of the output KL divergences on each distribution.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. In fact, some of the items are zero because of the sample size and some are zero because they'll literally never occur. Additionally, I'm interested in how different these two distributions are from each other as opposed to how different they are from some third distribution.

Comment: So if you know some items can never occur then you can remove them from your array or whatever data structure you use to store their counts. If you don't know they can never occur but you need to learn whether they can never occur then additive smoothing probably won't hurt. Besides for that - you need to know how different they are but do you need an accurate estimation of the KL divergence? does the number mean something to you? Probably more useful is a hypothesis test to test whether they are the same distribution or not. Check out the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for example